# Split text into different columns from the right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a string of alpha-numeric text that is in one cell of Excel, using v2016. the text is similar to:
 `ECN 6120 012 MMR 12195 201481`

I have used variants of the "search" and "find" and "trim" to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and last groups of text into individual cells.

I need to get the second to last group of numbers but it needs to be grabbed from the right because the 'MMR' sometimes is not present.
Any ideas?

Comment: If the data is of fixed length ,you can use right function. Otherwise ,if the data is delimited by spaces you can use instr along with right to get them

Comment: that's exactly the problem, the string prior to the bit that I want to pull out, the 12195 is not fixed, sometimes there is a MMR or similar, and sometimes not, so I'm trying to grab it from the right, but can't figure out how to nest it as between the 1st and 2nd space from the right.

Comment: Are there ALWAYS either five OR six fields formatted exactly as that with a single space separating them?

Comment: So far, yes, 5 or six fields with one space between each field, if there are 6 fields total then I can ignore the fourth field.  Maybe I need to just add another column and delete the extra field if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Comment: how can I grab the text that you have in column F if the text that you have in column E is sometimes not included in the text string cell A1?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UDF to do this.

In VBE, create a new module and drop this code in:

```
Function strtok(strIn As String, strDelim As String, intToken As Integer) As String
   strtok = Split(strIn, strDelim)(intToken - 1)
End Function
```

You can use this on your sheet then by using formula:

```
=strtok(A1, " ", 4)
```

To get the 4th word in that cell.

Comment: thanks, but trying not to do with VB as I really know nothing about it and not time to learn right now