# How do I separate a String into multiple cells by specific character in excel?

Tags: excel

How do I separate a string in a excel cell so that I can place the result into different cells.

Apple_watch_1stGen_Used
Apple_watch_2ndGen_New
Apple_iPhone_5s_New
Apple_iPhone_5s_Used_referb

and what I want to do in excel is in other cells to separate those values so that I can have them as in the image. What I want is that the tokens should appear as the are shown here. I only have column A right now

[image]

What I have done is used the FIND function to look for the "_" then add those to the B column to give me the token found. then add more but it becomes complicated and not practical. is there an easier way?
K2 cell formula (this is where I start counting the number of characters)

```
=FIND("_",$B2)
```

L2 cell formula gets more complicated

```
=FIND("_",$B2,K2+1)
```

M2 cell formula gets more complicated then N,O,P... should be even more complicated from what I have

```
FIND("_",$B2,L2+1),LEN($B2)
```

---

in the token series I have this 
B2 cell formaula

```
=MID($B2,K2+1,L2-K2-1)
```

Comment: Would you be willing to use a UDF (Custom VBA code, but interacted with using a formula?). I've provided a very lightweight UDF in the past to do exactly this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349415/split-text-into-different-columns-from-the-right

Comment: Use Text to Columns, it is on the data tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Split Function of Excel VBA to make a new Function, i once used it and got from the internet, don't know the author to credit.

Just input the code on a Excel VBA module.

This is the code to describe the new function:

```
Sub DescribeFunction()
   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1 To 3) As String

   FuncName = "EXTRACTELEMENT"
   FuncDesc = "Returns the nth element of a string that uses a separator character/Retorna o enésimo elemento da string que usa um caractér separador."
   Category = 7 'Text category
   ArgDesc(1) = "String that contains the elements/String que contém o elemento"
   ArgDesc(2) = "Element number to return/ Número do elemento a retornar"
   ArgDesc(3) = "Single-character element separator/ Elemento único separador (spc por padrão)"

   Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

And this is the function:

```
 Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
 EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Txt), Separator)(n - 1)
 End Function
```

Where you have to input the (Cell, number, separator: in your case "_")

For example: Apple_watch_1stGen_Used is on A1

EXTRACTELEMENT(A1,1,"_") would output Apple

EXTRACTELEMENT(A1,2,"_") would output watch

And so on...

You could use the Split function to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `Text-to-Columns` wizard (on the `Data` tab).  But if you need an Excel formula:

First define a Named formula.  This formula creates an array of values in the sequence `{1,99,198, ...}`

```
seq_99  Refers To:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Then, use this formula:

```
B2:  =INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),COLUMNS($A:A))
```

Fill across and down as needed

[image]

Algorithm:

- Replace the `split` character with a large number of <kbd>space</kbd>'s
- Use `MID` to return an array of values, by using an array constant for `start_num`
- `TRIM` each element in the array to get rid of the extra spaces.
- `INDEX` can now be used to sequentially return each element in the array.

If you use the Formula Evaluation tool, you can see each step in operation.