# EXCEL: Split numbers from the right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to keep a string of numbers from a Excel cell grabbed from the right and then the rest on the left to be deleted?:

I would like to keep the first 4 characters from right to left.

What I have:

```
222333444555
88
222333444
9933
```

The result that I am looking for:

```
4555
3444
9933
```

Less than 4 characters could be deleted. In this sample the 88 number was deleted as well.

The easy "aparently" solution is to splits the cells manually with the "Text to Columns" option, but this option start grabbing characters from the left. I need it grabbed from the right.

I tried already RIGHT and LEFT fuctions, but it deletes characters from the left or right. I have not fixed length as you can see, so it doesn't work.

Also I tried to analyze the following already answered question in a similar case, but I can not find the right answer:

[Split text into different columns from the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349415/split-text-into-different-columns-from-the-right)

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ummm.... `=IF(LEN(A1)>=4,RIGHT(A1,4),"")`?

Comment: Thanks Scott, excellent! It works nicely perfect.